# Размер watermark imagine

Tags: php, yii2, gd, imagick

Мне на картинку необходимо вставить текстовый watermark
использую следующий код:

```
Image::text(
            $image,
            $word,
            Yii::getAlias('@webroot/fonts/fira_sans/FiraSans-Book.otf'),
            $start,
            $fontOptions
        )->save(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/images/certificates/'.$name.'.jpg'), ['quality' => 100]);
```

Проблема в том что количество символов в watermark всегда разное, а мне надпись нужно сделать четко по центру. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, Yii'шный `Image` так не умеет, но он может вернуть `Imagine` (`getImagine`). Ну а дальше по [доке](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/API/): `Image::getImagine()->getClassFactory()->createFont(...)->box('text')` -- так вы узнаете размер бокса с текстом. Ну и останется посчитать позицию с которой нарисовать текст (середина картинки минус половина размера бокса текста).

UPD

В yii используется более [старая версия](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/_static/API/) Imagine, поэтому код будет немного другой:

```
$palette = new \Imagine\Image\Palette\RGB();
$fontBox = Image::getImagine()
    ->font('fontfile.ttf', 10, $palette->color('#ff0000'))
    ->box('foo bar');
var_dump($fontBox->getWidth(), $fontBox->getHeight());die;
```

Comment: Принцип понял, но не совсем понятно, как реализовать, можете пожалуйста написать по подробнее первое действие?

Comment: @Анатолий, обновил ответ. На самом деле разобраться в этом проще чем кажется (я впервые использую yii и imagine). 1. узнайте о возможностях библиотеки, которую используете, читая документацию и код (https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/doc/api/2.2/yii-imagine-image). 2. Придумайте решение с использованием этого функционала или убедитесь, что решения нет.

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо, это сработало!